# Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dependencies, android-sdk-tools, pubspec

"E/flutter ( 6763): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)"

This was  the  error that i am getting.

And Here is the My code ..

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
 import 'firstpage.dart';
 import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
 void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MaterialApp(
   routes: {
   '/home':(context){
    return Homepage();
   },
   '/first':(context){
    return First_Page();
  }
  },
  ));
  }
  class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
   const Homepage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
  }

 class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
 final Future<FirebaseApp> _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();
 final _auth= FirebaseAuth.instance;
 final _user=TextEditingController();
 final _pass=TextEditingController();
  String email='';
 String password='';
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      title: Text(
       'Sign-Up',
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
    ),
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
     child: Column(
       children: [
         Padding(
           padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 250),
         ),
          Container(
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _user,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Email-id",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                )
              ),
            ),
          ),
         SizedBox(height: 10,),
         Container(
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: _pass,
               decoration: InputDecoration(
                 hintText: "Password",
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
               )
             ),
           ),
         ),
         FlatButton(
           color: Colors.blue,
           child: Text('Sign-up'),
           onPressed: () async {

            await Firebase.initializeApp();
            email=_user.toString();
            password=_pass.toString();
            try{
             final newuser= await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: 
              password);
             if(newuser!=null){
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/First_Page');
             }
            }
           catch(e){
             print('error');
               }
              },
                     ),
                   ],
                ),
                ),
            );
          }
      }

  Here are the dependencies in my pubspec.yaml

 dependencies:
   flutter:
   sdk: flutter
   firebase_auth: ^3.2.0
   firebase_core : ^1.10.0
  

    And here are all the errors that i am getting...

    E/flutter ( 6763): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 
    MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on 
    channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core)
    E/flutter ( 6763): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod 
    (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:154:7)
     E/flutter ( 6763): <asynchronous suspension>
     E/flutter ( 6763): #1      MethodChannel.invokeListMethod 
    (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:342:35)
     E/flutter ( 6763): <asynchronous suspension>
     E/flutter ( 6763): #2      MethodChannelFirebase._initializeCore
    (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_
     firebase.dart:31:23)
     E/flutter ( 6763): <asynchronous suspension>
     E/flutter ( 6763): #3      MethodChannelFirebase.initializeApp 
     (package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/method_channel
     /method_channel_firebase.dart:73:7)
     E/flutter ( 6763): <asynchronous suspension>
      E/flutter ( 6763): #4      Firebase.initializeApp 
      (package:firebase_core/src/firebase.dart:42:31)
      E/flutter ( 6763): <asynchronous suspension>
      E/flutter ( 6763): #5      main (package:firebase/main.dart:7:3)
      E/flutter ( 6763): <asynchronous suspension>
      E/flutter ( 6763):
```

These all error appears after successfully restarting of my application.

Comment: Did you add google-services plugin in build.gradle?

Comment: yes @PeterHaddad

Answer (score 0):

Import this in MainActivity.kt

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterFragmentActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant
```

and extend your class

```
FlutterFragmentActivity()
```

then add

```
override fun configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)
    }
```